# What's a word to call a person who is involuntarily used?

Tags: single-word-requests, connotation

In an interaction, one person uses another against their will. Is there a word (noun) to refer to that person?

**Example:** Person A trips and grabs onto Person B, a stranger, in order to not fall to the ground. Person B had no choice in the matter. Person A would label Person B their _____.

*Dupe, instrument, pawn, puppet, stooge,* and *tool* have pretty negative connotations, so don't quite work. The interaction is more of a slight inconvenience.

Comment: _guinea pig_ maybe

Comment: I'm not sure there is one. You would probably need to coin something - like "sorry to use you as a zimmer frame".

Answer (score -1):

One who saves from danger is a saviour (American savior).

> savior = one that saves from danger or destruction
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/savior)

The question then arises: can a savior be involuntary?

Merriam Webster continues with an example “the policeman proved to be our savior, arriving on the scene just as we were about to be mugged”. The policemen may easily have arrived by chance, making him an involuntary savior.

Another example where the savior is most certainly involuntary (even inimical) is:

> James Murdoch wants to blow up the BBC. He could yet turn out to be its unwitting saviour.
>
> [Financial Times](https://www.ft.com/content/40994eba-9bdd-11de-b214-00144feabdc0)

“Oops! Sorry! I nearly fell in the mud. You are my saviour.”

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain themselves so that the questioner may benefit from their wisdom?

Comment: +1. I like the idea of a involuntary/inimical saviour. Btw I confess I had to look up *inimical* !

Comment: +1 but it is Person A being saved who "uses" the unwitting "saviour" (B). Maybe the idea of being someone's anchor or lifebelt–unless it's grabbed or worn, it is useless– might be more appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

You are my (a):

**Lifesaver**

a thing that saves one from serious difficulty. Also, a person who rescues another from danger of death, especially from drowning. a person or thing that saves a person, as from a difficult situation or critical moment: That money was a lifesaver ([www.dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com) › browse › lifesaver
).

Can also be used in a non-literal sense such as:

**Guardian Angel**

a spirit who is believed to protect and help a particular person (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/guardian-angel)' or;

**Knight in shining armour**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-knight-in-shining-armour?topic=preserving-and-saving

More tentatively: http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/save-(one%27s)-butt

Comment: These adjectives suggest the person had a choice in the matter. I wouldn't ever apply these to someone who acted involuntary.

Comment: I understand your point@dwiz. I'm not sure whether there's such a word as 'wordcreep' as these words are IMO becoming non-literal (or should I say meta-literal). Most people who are used to prevent another from falling dow do not themselves fall down, At some point the person being used volunteered some eneregy to prevent themselves from harm, thereby acting voluntarily: albeit a reflex action.

Comment: Person A is at death's door, due to starvation, and person B, inadvertently, drops some money, If Person A takes the money and unbeknown to Person B, buys food and recovers, is person B a lifesaver?

Answer (score -1):

If it doesn't have to be possessive, maybe "solid" would work.  Literally true and metaphorically fitting for the example.  In this case, the involuntary use is just "using" the body as a solid.

> "You're solid, thanks."

> "Dude, you're solid."

> "You're my solid"

Last one just doesn't flow off the tongue as well

Comment: "To be solid" for me means something more like reliable or sound.  Or as in a solid favor?  I agree, the possessive doesn't quite hold up. An authoritative reference would help with this. I encourage you to keep working on it and welcome you to EL&U.